# BubbleSort error LNK2019

Tags: c++

This is my cpp code and the error Im getting

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl selectionSort(int * const,int &,int &)" (?selectionSort@@YAXQAHAAH1@Z) referenced in function _main

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int[], int&, int&);
void inserionSort (int [], int&, int&);
void generateRandomArray ( int [], int [], int []);
void selectionSort (int[], int&, int&);

const int length=5000;



  int main()
    {
        int compBubbleSort =0;
        int assignBubbleSort=0;
        int list1[length], list2 [length], list3[length];
    generateRandomArray( list1, list2, list3);

    cout<<"****************Bubble sort*****************"<<endl;

    bubbleSort( list1, compBubbleSort, assignBubbleSort);

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Number of compBubbleSort are :"<< compBubbleSort<<endl;
    cout<<"Number of  Assignments are :"<< assignBubbleSort<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    compBubbleSort = 0;
    assignBubbleSort = 0;
    cout<<"**********Selection sort***************"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    selectionSort (list2, compBubbleSort, assignBubbleSort);

    cout<<"Number of compBubbleSort are:"<< compBubbleSort <<endl;
    cout<<"Number of  Assignments are :"<< assignBubbleSort<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    compBubbleSort=0;
    assignBubbleSort=0;
    cout<<"****************Insertion sort*******************"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    inserionSort (list2, compBubbleSort, assignBubbleSort);
    cout<<"Number of compBubbleSort are:"<< compBubbleSort <<endl;
    cout<<"Number of  Assignments are :"<< assignBubbleSort<<endl;

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

void generateRandomArray( int list1[], int list2 [], int list3[])
{
    srand(time_t(0));

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        list1 [i]= list2[i]= list3[i]=rand()%20000;

}

void bubbleSort (int num[], int &compBubbleSort, int &assignBubbleSort)
{
    for(int iter=1; iter<length; iter++)
    {
        for(int index=1; index<length; index++)
        {
            compBubbleSort++;
            if(num [index]>num[index+1])
            {
                int temp= num[index];
                num[index] = num[index+1];
                num[index+1]=temp;
                assignBubbleSort++;
            }
        }
    }
}

void seletionSort( int num[], int &compBubbleSort, int &assignBubbleSort)
{
    int index;
    int smallestIndex;
    int location;
    int temp;

    for (index=0; index<length-1; index++)
    {
        smallestIndex=index;

        for(location=index+1;location<length;location++)
        {
            compBubbleSort++;
            if(num[location]<num[smallestIndex])
            {
                smallestIndex=location;
            }
        }
         temp= num[smallestIndex];

         num[smallestIndex] =num[index];
         assignBubbleSort= assignBubbleSort+3;
         num[index] = temp;
    }
}

void inserionSort (int num[], int &compBubbleSort, int&assignments)
{
    int firstOutOfOrder,location;
    int temp;

    for (firstOutOfOrder=1; firstOutOfOrder<length;firstOutOfOrder++)
    {
        if(num[firstOutOfOrder]<num[firstOutOfOrder-1])
        {
        compBubbleSort++;
        temp= num[firstOutOfOrder];
        location=firstOutOfOrder;
        assignments=assignments+2;

            do
            {
                num[location]=num[location-1];
                assignments++;
                location--;
                compBubbleSort++;
            }
            while(location>0 &&num[location-1]>temp);
            num[location]=temp;
            assignments++;

        }   
    }
}
```

Can some one explain the error 2019 because most of my programs have it.

Comment: `seletionSort`....use this -> `c`.

Comment: That looks like an undefined reference error. Perhaps it's not being defined or you're not linking the library.

Comment: This is not a bubble sort error. Look again. The fact that most of your programs have it proves the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your function definition.

Change:

```
void seletionSort( int num[], int &compBubbleSort, int &assignBubbleSort)
```

to:

```
void selectionSort( int num[], int &compBubbleSort, int &assignBubbleSort)
//       ^
```

That's why your linker couldn't find `selectionSort`.